# Python 3.6.1: Code does not execute after a for loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I've been learning Python and I wanted to write a script to count the number of characters in a text and calculate their relative frequencies. But first, I wanted to know the length of the file. My intention is that, while the script goes from line to line counting all the characters, it would print the current line and the total number of lines, so I could know how much it is going to take.

I executed a simple for loop to count the number of lines, and then another for loop to count the characters and put them in a dictionary. However, when I run the script with the first for loop, it stops early. It doesn't even go into the second for loop as far as I know. If I remove this loop, the rest of the code goes on fine. What is causing this?

Excuse my code. It's rudimentary, but I'm proud of it.

My code:

```
import string

fname = input ('Enter a file name: ')

try:
    fhand = open(fname)

except:
    print ('Cannot open file.')
    quit()

#Problematic bit. If this part is present, the script ends abruptly.
#filelength = 0
#for lines in fhand:
#    filelength = filelength + 1

counts = dict()
currentline = 1
for line in fhand:
    if len(line) == 0: continue
    line = line.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation))
    line = line.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.digits))
    line = line.translate(str.maketrans('','',string.whitespace))
    line = line.translate(str.maketrans('','',""" '"’‘“” """))
    line = line.lower()
    index = 0
    while index < len(line):
        if line[index] not in counts:
            counts[line[index]] = 1
        else:
            counts[line[index]] += 1
        index += 1
    print('Currently at line: ', currentline, 'of', filelength)
    currentline += 1

listtosort = list()
totalcount = 0

for (char, number) in list(counts.items()):
    listtosort.append((number,char))
    totalcount = totalcount + number

listtosort.sort(reverse=True)
for (number, char) in listtosort:
    frequency = number/totalcount*100
    print ('Character: %s, count: %d, Frequency: %g' % (char, number, frequency))
```

Comment: If the first loop is present, it consumes all of the lines in the file, leaving none for the second loop to read.  You'd need to do `fhand.seek(0)` between the loops to rewind the file.

Comment: When I tried to count Pride and Prejudice I got from Project Gutenberg, I had to include that line because it would compute those quotes in the statistics. They weren't removed in the other translates. It is kind of a makeshift solution really.

Comment: Oh I see now. So there's a hidden counter that keeps track at which line I'm at, and then I have to reset it with fhand.seek(0). I think I had in my mind that it would reset itself on each for loop. I did not know that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine the way you are doing it, however to simulate your problem, I downloaded and saved a Guttenberg text book. It's a unicode issue. Two ways to resolve it. Open it as a binary file or add the encoding. As it's text, I'd go the utf-8 option.

I'd also suggest you code it differently, below is the **basic structure** that closes the file after opening it.

```
filename = "GutenbergBook.txt"
try:
    #fhand = open(filename, 'rb')
    #open read only and utf-8 encoding
    fhand = open(filename, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8')
except IOError:
    print("couldn't find the file")
else:
    try:
        for line in fhand:
            #put your code here
            print(line)
    except:
        print("Error reading the file")
finally:
    fhand.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. I will keep these peculiarities in mind. I am still getting the hang of the open command, encoding, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For the op, this is a specific occasion. However, for visitors, if your code below the for state does not execute, it is not a python built-in issue, most likely to be: **an exception error handling in parent caller**.

Your iteration is inside a function, which is called inside a try except block of caller, then if any error occur during the loop, it will get escaped.

This issue can be hard to find, especially when you dealing with intricate architecture.